# Different certificates for the same website?

Tags: tls, certificates, openssl

When I load https://objective-see.com in Safari, it shows me a certificate with CN=objective-see.com. However, when I retrieve the certificate using

```
echo -e | openssl s_client -connect "objective-see.com:443" 2>/dev/null | awk '/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/, /END CERTIFICATE/ { print }'
```

I get `CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2`

Why? Is this a CDN phenomenon?

Answer (score 3):

`openssl s_client` does not use [Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) by default while the browser does. To force SNI use the `-servername` parameter:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect objective-see.com:443 -servername objective-see.com |\
  openssl x509 -text
...
Subject: CN=objective-see.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If that still does not work, could it be due to client certificate-based authentication failures? The symptoms are

- The SSL handshake failure while client certificate authenticating
- system logs error messages indicating SSL handshake failures.

A client usually has its store of Certificate Authority (CA) certificates in its Trusted Device Certificate so if the certificate is not there, then the system logs will indicate error.

You will need to add the unknown or new certificate as a trusted root certificate.